# gdal 2.1 Rasterize

Tags: python, gdal, rasterize

Is it possible to set the data type (Byte, Float32) when using gdal.Rasterize in gdal 2.1? Currently, I use gdal.Translate to convert to Byte, but this is inefficient.

```
tif = my/target.tif
shp = my/source.shp
tiftemp = my/temp/solution.tif
rasterizeOptions = gdal.RasterizeOptions(xRes=20, yRes=20, allTouched=True etc.)
gdal.Rasterize(tiftemp, shp, options=rasterizeOptions)
#translate to Byte data type (not supported by Rasterize?)
gdal.Translate(tif, tiftemp, outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte,
                       creationOptions=['COMPRESS=PACKBITS')
```

I am aware that it is possible to use

```
subprocess.check_call('gdal_rasterize', '-ot', 'byte' ...)
```

but I would prefer to avoid this if possible. Any ideas?

Comment: As long as `tifftemp` - the dataset into which you are rasterizing, is set to the correct type, you should be fine.

Comment: gdal.RasterizeOptions(outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte)  raises TypeError: RasterizeOptions() got an unexpected keyword argument 'outputType'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in gdal 2.1.2, use gdal.RasterizeOptions() as if you were using it on the command line:

```
opts_str = '-ot Byte'
rast_opts = gdal.RasterizeOptions(options=opts_str)
```

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed in GDAL 2.1.3. Previously the data type was hard-coded and not exposed in the Python bindings. See https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6710.